# Azure File Share - Recursive Directory Search like os.walk

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-files, azure-storage-files

I am writing a Python script to download files from Azure File Share. The structure of the File Share is as below:

```
/analytics/Part1/file1.txt
/analytics/Part1/file2.txt
/analytics/mainfile.txt
/analytics/Part1/Part1_1/file11.txt
```

I tried to use the following lines in my script but it looks for files and directories only at the root directory level.

```py
fileshareclient = ShareClient(
    account_url=args.get('AccountURL'),
    credential=args.get('SASKey'),
    share_name=args.get('FileShare')
)

fileLst = list(
    fileshareclient.list_directories_and_files('analytics')
)
```

The output is:

```
/analytics/mainfile.txt  --> File
/analytics/Part1 --> Dir
```

But, I am looking for something like `os.walk()` function in Python here to achieve this recursive directory walk. Any idea if such function is available in Azure File Service Python API?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [built-in `list_directories_and_files()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.sharedirectoryclient?view=azure-python#list-directories-and-files-name-starts-with-none----kwargs-) of the [Azure Storage File Share client library for Python `azure-storage-file-share`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file-share) only lists the root directories and files. If you want to something like `os.walk()`, you should write the method by yourself.

Here, I write a function which can recursively list all the files / directories and it works fine(please feel free to modify it if it does not meet your need):

```
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareServiceClient

def list_recursive(directory_client,directory_name):
    sub_client = directory_client.get_subdirectory_client(directory_name)
    myfiles = sub_client.list_directories_and_files()

    for file in myfiles:
        print(file.get('name'))
        if file.get('is_directory'):
            list_recursive(sub_client,file.get('name'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn_str="xxxx"
    file_service = ShareServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str)

    share_client = file_service.get_share_client("your_share_name")
    d_client = share_client.get_directory_client("your_directory_name")
    myfiles = d_client.list_directories_and_files()

    for file in myfiles:
        print(file.get('name'))
        if file.get('is_directory'):
            list_recursive(d_client,file.get('name'))
```

Comment: thanks.. it works !! To collect the file metadata and its full path, I used fileclient getfileproperties() and used a list to capture all the files

Comment: How would you change the code to get the full directory/folder path for each file?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I find it a bit confusing having to deal with two different methods to do "the same thing". I prefer to instantiate the directory client via the `from_connection_string` method, as in the following approach.

#### Python Requirements

```
pip install azure-storage-file-share==12.6.0
```

#### Python Script

FileShare file listing:

```
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareServiceClient, ShareDirectoryClient, ShareFileClient
from typing import Iterator, Union
import os


def list_files(
    dir_path: str,
    share_name: str,
    connection_string: str,
    include_properties: bool = False,
    recursive: bool = True
) -> Iterator[Union[str, dict]]:
    """
    List files from FileShare on Azure Storage Account.

    Parameters
    ----------
    dir_path: str
        Directory path to list files from.
    share_name: str
        FileShare name.
    connection_string: str
        Connection string.
    include_properties: bool
        Specifies that file properties to be returned in the response.
    recursive: bool
        Specifies whether to list files recursively.

    Returns
    -------
    files_list: Iterator[Union[str, dict]]
        List of filepaths from FileShare.
        Returns a list of strings (Iterator[str]) if 'include_properties' is false.
        Otherwise, return a list of dictionaries (Iterator[dict]).

    Notes
    -----
    This method only lists files, ignoring empty directories.

    References
    ----------
    .. [1] Method 'list_files': https://stackoverflow.com/a/71088269/16109419
    .. [2] Recursive files listing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66543222/16109419
    """
    dir_client = ShareDirectoryClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str=connection_string,
        share_name=share_name,
        directory_path=dir_path
    )

    # Listing files from current directory path:
    for file in dir_client.list_directories_and_files():
        name, is_directory = file['name'], file['is_directory']
        path = os.path.join(dir_path, name)

        if is_directory:
            if recursive:
                # Listing files recursively:
                childrens = list_files(
                    dir_path=path,
                    share_name=share_name,
                    connection_string=connection_string,
                    include_properties=include_properties,
                    recursive=recursive
                )

                for child in childrens:
                    yield child
        else:
            if include_properties:
                file_client = ShareFileClient.from_connection_string(
                    conn_str=connection_string,
                    share_name=share_name,
                    file_path=path
                )

                yield file_client.get_file_properties()
            else:
                yield path
```

FileShare file listing example:

```
def main() -> None:
    connection_string = "<your-conn-str>"
    share_name = "<your-share-name>"
    dir_path = ""  # Leave it empty to list files from root directory.

    files_list = list_files(
        dir_path=dir_path,
        share_name=share_name,
        connection_string=connection_string,
        include_properties=False,
        recursive=True
    )

    for i, f in enumerate(files_list, start=1):
        print(i, f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```