# differences between get_directory_client and get_subdirectory_client for azure file share

Tags: azure-files, azure-storage-files

Azure file share Python SDKs have two similar methods `get_directory_client` and `get_subdirectory_client`. It seems both are interacting with directories. But do we need two methods to perform the same task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_directory_client` is to get the root directory, and `get_subdirectory_client` is to get the subdirectories of the current directory.

As you can see from the document, you must get the [ShareClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.shareclient?view=azure-python) object first. At this time, you can only call [get_directory_client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.shareclient?view=azure-python#get-directory-client-directory-path-none-) to get the root directory, and then you will get the [ShareDirectoryClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.sharedirectoryclient?view=azure-python) object. At this time, if you want to get the subdirectory , You can only call the [get_subdirectory_client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.sharedirectoryclient?view=azure-python#get-subdirectory-client-directory-name----kwargs-) method.

You can also refer to the [description of the file share client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage-file-share-readme?view=azure-python#clients) to understand the difference:

[image]

==========================update======================

```
    connection_string = "<your-connection-string>"
    service = ShareServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string)
    share = service.get_share_client("<your-file-share-name>")
    my_files = []
    for item in share.list_directories_and_files():
        my_files.append(item)
        if item["is_directory"]:
            for item2 in share.get_directory_client(item["name"]).list_directories_and_files():
                my_files.append(item)
                for item3 in share.get_directory_client(item["name"]).get_subdirectory_client(item2["name"]).list_directories_and_files():
                    my_files.append(item3)
        else:
            my_files.append(item)
    print(my_files)
```

You can refer to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/storage-file-share-readme?view=azure-python#listing-contents-of-a-directory).

Comment: Hmm. That seems a bit confusing. What you describes seems requiring a `subdirectory_client` for each subfolder, is my understanding correct? For example, if my share has 3 hierarchies:L1/L11/file1.txt,L2/L22/file2.txt, then `get_directory_client` will return me ["L1","L2"], to get "L11" and "L22", I need create two `get_subdirectory_client`? Do you have a working example showing how to get all folders or files recursively?

Comment: @derek. According to your needs, the code can be written like this.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I find it a bit confusing having to deal with two different methods to do "the same thing". I prefer to instantiate the directory client via the `from_connection_string` method.

For more information on how to list files from a FileShare, take a look at the following post: ["Azure File Share - Recursive Directory Search like os.walk"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71088269/16109419). The approach I reported allows to list files recursively, walking through the directories.